# Google reader public RSS get more than 9 items

Tags: url, rss, limit, google-reader

We need to parse the data from a google reader public rss feed, the problem is that the url parameter n=numerofitemstoretrieve only works up to n=9

For example in our test url:

http://www.google.com/reader/shared/user%2F15926769355350523044%2Flabel%2FPublicas%20RSS?n=2

Retrieves 2 news items

http://www.google.com/reader/shared/user%2F15926769355350523044%2Flabel%2FPublicas%20RSS?n=20

Retrieves only 9 news items

How can we overcome this limitation? Is there another parameter for this case? Or another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that using this alternative url the n parameter works fine:

https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/contents/feed/http://www.google.com/reader/public/atom/user%2F15926769355350523044%2Flabel%2FPublicas%20RSS?n=20

The only problem is the output format its different this way, so if someone finds a better solution we will grant the response to him/her

It seems the results are cropped only when the url is viewed in the browser...if you get the web contents from code it returns the correct item count...(in contrast using the alternative url the returned contents are right both ways: getting them from code as well as viewing it in the browser)

Answer (score 1):

In Atom format (link in the top right in the two urls in the OP) :
http://www.google.com/reader/public/atom/user%2F15926769355350523044%2Flabel%2FPublicas%20RSS?n=20

The content with /api/ in the URL in the second post is in JSON format, slightly harder to parse than the Atom XML.

https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26567/how-to-raise-google-reader-rss-feed-entry-limit