# Google News RSS - Get More than 10 Items

Tags: rss, google-reader, google-news

I am trying to get news from the Google News RSS and display it in an app. The problem is that Google News RSS only gives me 10 items and I can not figure out how to get the next page and/or get more than 10 items.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google reader public RSS get more than 9 items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247399/google-reader-public-rss-get-more-than-9-items)

Answer (score 12):

Append &num=100 to the end of the feed URL.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-reader-howdoi/bL3iyVFtcLg

Comment: How to go to page 2?